# PIL's Image.rotate gives me 90 degrees instead of 270 degrees

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

Python 3.11.8
PIL 10.2.0

I'm trying to rotate this image by 270 degrees:

[image]

My code:

```
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open("test.jpg")
image = image.rotate(270, expand=True)
image.save("test_out.jpg")
```

But the result is:

[image]

which to me is a 90 degree rotation

I suspected that auto-orientation and exif data is messing with me, so I tried these commands separately before the rotation but they did not help getting the expected result either:

```
image = ImageOps.exif_transpose(image)
image.getexif().clear()
```

When I do it with another tool:

```
convert test.jpg -rotate 270 test_out.jpg
```

I get the expected result:

[image]

Comment: According to the documentation of [`rotate`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.rotate) it rotates counter-clockwise.

Comment: and what is the question?

Answer (score 2):

```
# To switch rotation i.e. counterclockwise to clockwise 
# Use negative value
image = image.rotate(-270, expand=True)
image
```

output:

[image]

By default rotation is counterclockwise, as can be seen from:
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.rotate

> ```
> Image.rotate(angle, resample=Resampling.NEAREST, expand=0,
>              center=None, translate=None, fillcolor=None)
> ```
>
> Returns a rotated copy of this image. This method returns a copy of this image, rotated the given number of degrees counter clockwise around its centre.
>
> PARAMETERS:
>
> `angle` – In degrees counter clockwise.
>
> `resample` – An optional resampling filter. This can be one of `Resampling.NEAREST` (use nearest neighbour), `Resampling.BILINEAR` (linear interpolation in a 2x2 environment), or `Resampling.BICUBIC` (cubic spline interpolation in a 4x4 environment). If omitted, or if the image has mode “1” or “P”, it is set to `Resampling.NEAREST`. See Filters.
>
> `expand` – Optional expansion flag. If true, expands the output image to make it large enough to hold the entire rotated image. If false or omitted, make the output image the same size as the input image. Note that the expand flag assumes rotation around the center and no translation.
>
> `center` – Optional center of rotation (a 2-tuple). Origin is the upper left corner. Default is the center of the image.
>
> `translate` – An optional post-rotate translation (a 2-tuple).
>
> `fillcolor` – An optional color for area outside the rotated image.
>
> RETURNS:
>
> An `Image` object.
>
> This rotates the input image by `theta` degrees **counter clockwise**

So your code is working correctly, you can change the direction with entering your value as negative

Comment: @tmdavision , hi tmdavision can you teach me how to add multiple > 's in an answer to achieve the effect you have just made on the edit

Comment: Select the text and click the "blockquote" button in the editor (or use CTRL+Q).